# Is there an adjective that means that something is part of the lore?

Tags: word-request

Is there an adjective that means that something is part of the lore? The word "lore-friendly" means something isn't in contradiction with the lore, but it doesn't necessarily mean something was mentioned in the book. Is there a word that's specifically tailored to mean the latter? I can't think of a single word that means that, but I swear there's a word for it.

Comment: Are you thinking of *folkloric* or *folklorish*?

Comment: folkloric can be used for novels like Games of Thrones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "canon". This means the object being discussed is accepted as part of the official lore. This is opposed to "non-canon" which means the object in contention had not been accepted as official for the moment (although sometimes it will get added later).

Answer (score 0):

"Canon" means something has been confirmed by the author of a piece of media. "The canon" refers to everything that is canon. You can either say that something is canon or that something is a part of the canon. Don't confuse canon with cannon (the weapon).